# In a component how to call a function in the controller that was received as a binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I'm trying to create a component that allows me to do some checks on an input and save with some delay so that it doesn't stress too much the database.

This is the simplified code with the part that i'm not being able to sort.
**The problem is that the updateFunction is undefined, how can I access it?**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.value = 2;
});


app.component('saveDelay', {
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" />',
  bindings: {
    inputValue: '=',
    updateFunction: '&'
  },
  controller: function($scope) {

    var saveTimer;

    $scope.$watch('inputValue',
      function(newValue, oldValue) {

        if (newValue === oldValue)
          return;

        clearTimeout( saveTimer );
        saveTimer = setTimeout( updateFunction, 1000 );
      }
    );
  }
});
```

the html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <save-delay input-value="value" update-function="Alert(value)" />
</div>
```

here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fph33y20/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `this` to access bindings inside controller. By default component controller's properties could be accessed with `$ctrl` inside component's template. The callback should be defined in the parent controller as well.

Here is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {   
  this.alert = function(rate){ console.log(rate); }; 
  this.rateCol = {
   rate: 10
  };
}]);


app.component('saveDelay', {
  restrict: 'E',
  template: '<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.inputValue" />',
  bindings: {
    inputValue: '=',
    updateFunction: '&'
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;

    var saveTimer;

    $scope.$watch(function(){ return ctrl.inputValue; },
      function(newValue, oldValue) {

        if (newValue === oldValue)
          return;

        clearTimeout(saveTimer);
        saveTimer = setTimeout(function(){ ctrl.updateFunction({rate: newValue}); }, 1000);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl as mc">
  <save-delay input-value="mc.rateCol.rate" update-function="mc.alert(rate)" />
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```